# Search for duplicates in a RegEx capturing group?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I just matched a string with a Regular Expression.

I want to match a string that contains 3 letter/digit combo's.
It may contain a A, B or L following by a digit 1-3. (in case of a L, 1-4)

**My question:**
I don't want to match the string when a letter matches multiple times. So the A, B and L, only may occur once.

My expression so far:

```
(?:[A|L|B](?(?<=L)[1-4]|[1-3])){3}
```

Teststrings that match at this moment:

```
L2B1A3
B2L1A2
A1B1L4
A1A2A3
```

Strings that don't match at this moment:

```
L4B4A1 (Only L can have a digit that's 4)
L2A1B (Missing digit)
```

Strings that I don't want to match (matching now):

```
A2A2A3 (The A, B and L only may occur one time!)
```

Comment: how about this `^(?!.*[AB]4)([ALB])[1-4](?:(?!\1)([ALB])[1-4])(?:(?!\1|\2)([ALB])[1-4])$` ? demo https://www.regex101.com/r/VKGj0q/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew he don't want to match `A1A2A3`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: If the question was clear, I'd have posted the answer. Maybe OP needs [`^(?!([ALB]).*\1)(?:[AB][1-3]|L[1-4]){3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/uZflbO/5). **Milkmannetje**, could you please provide the comprehensive test case? What strings are valid and which ones are not?

Comment: I think my testcases are clear...

Comment: Then my regex is a bit shorter than the accepted equivalent one.

Comment: Wiktor, your regex matched A1A1A1. I don't wan't to match this.

Comment: @Milkmannetje: no it doesn't, however it allows the two last letters to be the same. `.*` is missing at the beginning of the lookahead. Note that since you only have three letters, you can also write all possible permutations.

Comment: Like that : https://regex101.com/r/YP0bG2/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Why would you do that? Is that faster? Because the expression in less readable now?

Comment: Maybe or not, it takes less steps than the others, but that doesn't prove anything (and I don't think speed is important for very small strings). About readability, It's not because a pattern is long that it is less readable, in particular when the idea is very simple. Note that you can also improve the readability using the x modifier: https://regex101.com/r/YP0bG2/3 (difficult to read or understand?)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Great! No just to read, not understand. Thanks for the (x) modifier example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this would work:

```
^(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*L)([AB][1-3]|L[1-4]){3}$
```

which gives

```
L2B1A3  - match
B2L1A2  - match
A1B1L4  - match
A1A2A3  - no match
L4B4A1  - no match
L2A1B   - no match
```

Break-down:

```
^             # start of string
(?=.*A)       # A must occur anywhere in the string
(?=.*B)       # B must occur anywhere in the string
(?=.*L)       # L must occur anywhere in the string
(             # begin capturing group
  [AB][1-3]   #   A or B and 1-3
  |           #   or
  L[1-4]      #   L and 1-4
){3}          # end group
$             # end of string
```

The fact that the three lookaheads must be satisfied while the main group must match three times *as well* takes care of the condition that the letters must not be doubled.

Comment: Yes, spot on! That's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Just offering an alternative method.

```
^(?!.*([A-Z]).*\1)(?:[AB][1-3]|L[1-4]){3}$
```

The negative lookahead with a backreference to capture group 1  `(?!.*([A-Z]).*\1)` ensures that an uppercase letter only occurs once in the string.

The advantage is just that the regex will be more concise when more letters than ABL are added to the regex.